# Bokeh application: No feedback in windows cmd

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd, bokeh

i am working with bokeh applications for the last few months. I always called them with os.system('bokeh serve --show myapplication.py').

After that the cmd of windows would always give me feedback (if the code is running) that the server is up and if I, for example print something in my code, I could see it as well in the windows console even if the application runs succesfully....

I used that information mostly for debugging, but for a few days now, the cmd keeps completly empty...

Does anybody know how the deal with this situation?

Thanks in advance & Best Regards

Comment: FWIW, in the vast majority of cases, calling Python scripts from Python scripts should be avoided. You can just embed Bokeh as a library and remove the whole layer of indirection with all its possible problems.

Comment: Is this possible without adding a environment variable? I am working on a machine without admin rights...

Comment: I don't have a clue what you mean. First of all, you _can_ set environment variables on a per shell or per process basis without admin rights. Second of all, running Bokeh doesn't require any environment variables as well, no matter if you use it as a script or as a library. You _can_ use them to customize some behavior, but they're not required.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't read your answer well enough...Thanks for the advice! I embed bokeh and try again and see if I get some terminal outputs again.